# iOS UISearchBar delay in showing keyboard after calling becomeFirstResponder - iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar which is an IBOutlet.  Tapping on the search bar or calling `[searchBar becomeFirstResponder]` in viewDidAppear results in a few seconds delay where the UI is locked before the keyboard appears.

I've looked at this in Instruments, and there is a CPU usage spike when becomeFirstResponder is called, but I'm not sure how I can narrow this down to a method / bunch of methods within the spike.

The view controller is not doing anything blocking, and there is nothing else running on the main thread (as far as I can see). This only happens the first time after calling becomeFirstResponder or tapping on the search bar. It does not happen again once the keyboard has been dismissed.

Any help would be much appreciated, as I can't see what's wrong really.

This is all running on iOS7, on iPhone and iPad BTW.

Comment: It is true that it is slow when you first time make the keyboard appear. I don't not get the reason, hope someone can give explanation.

Comment: Have you seen the same issue? Further investigation reveals that the delay seems to be with iOS itself rather than anything I've done.

Comment: yes, I agree with you.